# Adding conditions in joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

Table customers (typical table for user registration): name, creditcard_registered (you can have one or more)

The creditcards could be X, Y or Z

Table payments (payments): name, payment_amount, creditcard_used

I need to know all payments did with cards Y or Z by user with the condition that each customer had to register card X and they never used.

Thanks

TABLE customers

| NAME | CREDIT_CARD_REGISTERED |
| --- | --- |
| Bill | Z |
| Robert | X |
| Robert | Z |
| Thomas | X |
| Thomas | Y |
| Thomas | Z |
| Leroy | X |
| Leroy | Y |
| Leroy | Z |
| Martha | Y |
| Martha | Z |

TABLE payments

| NAME | AMOUNT | CREDIT_CARD_USED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bill | 50 | X |
| Robert | 75 | X |
| Thomas | 20 | X |
| Thomas | 30 | Y |
| Thomas | 40 | Y |
| Leroy | 45 | Y |
| Leroy | 50 | Y |
| Leroy | 75 | Z |
| Leroy | 20 | Y |
| Leroy | 50 | Z |
| Martha | 30 | X |
| Martha | 50 | Y |
| Martha | 40 | Z |

So my query must return all amounts of Leroy (all his cards Y and Z. Because is the only one who has credit card X registered and it had not been used.

I used

```
SELECT * 
FROM A
LEFT JOIN payments ON customers.name = payments.name
           AND customers.CREDIT_CARD_REGISTERED = 'X'
           AND count(payments.CREDIT_CARD_USED) = 0
```

Comment: The creditcards could be X Y or Z , I need to know all payments did with cards Y and Z by user with the condition that ecah customer had to register card A and they never used. - where does card A come from?

Comment: Please provide examples of what you have done so far and what/why it is not working.  With table structures helps as well with data exmples.

Comment: Table names A and B are poor. Choose names that make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for payment information based on 2 conditions:

1. Customers who have registered `X`
2. Customers who have not used `X`

I have slightly modified your example data to give us more examples to work with. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a930b/14 for a working example, but in summary:

- Bill

  - not registered X (should not be selected)
  - used X
- Robert

  - registered X
  - used X (should not be selected)
- Thomas

  - registered X
  - used X (should not be selected)
- Leroy

  - registered X
  - not used X
- Martha

  - not registered X (should not be selected)
  - not used X
- Sam

  - registered X
  - not used X

Full working example data:

```
CREATE TABLE customers
    (`NAME` varchar(6), `CREDIT_CARD_REGISTERED` varchar(1))
;
    
INSERT INTO customers
    (`NAME`, `CREDIT_CARD_REGISTERED`)
VALUES
    ('Bill', 'Z'),
    ('Robert', 'X'),
    ('Robert', 'Z'),
    ('Thomas', 'X'),
    ('Thomas', 'Y'),
    ('Thomas', 'Z'),
    ('Leroy', 'X'),
    ('Leroy', 'Y'),
    ('Leroy', 'Z'),
    ('Martha', 'Y'),
    ('Martha', 'Z'),
    ('Sam', 'X'),
    ('Sam', 'Z')
;

CREATE TABLE payments
    (`NAME` varchar(6), `AMOUNT` int, `CREDIT_CARD_USED` varchar(1))
;
    
INSERT INTO payments
    (`NAME`, `AMOUNT`, `CREDIT_CARD_USED`)
VALUES
    ('Bill', 50, 'X'),
    ('Robert', 75, 'X'),
    ('Thomas', 20, 'X'),
    ('Thomas', 30, 'Y'),
    ('Thomas', 40, 'Y'),
    ('Leroy', 45, 'Y'),
    ('Leroy', 50, 'Y'),
    ('Leroy', 75, 'Z'),
    ('Leroy', 20, 'Y'),
    ('Leroy', 50, 'Z'),
    -- ('Martha', 30, 'X'),
    ('Martha', 50, 'Y'),
    ('Martha', 40, 'Z'),
    -- ('Sam', 30, 'X'),
    ('Sam', 50, 'Y'),
    ('Sam', 40, 'Z')
;
```

---

We can start by selecting names from `customers` where `CREDIT_CARD_REGISTERED = 'X'` to know which customers to potentially include:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  NAME
FROM
  customers
WHERE
  CREDIT_CARD_REGISTERED = 'X';
```

This returns:

```
Robert
Thomas
Leroy
Sam
```

Then select names from payments where the customer has used `X`, so we can exclude these users:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  NAME
FROM
  payments
WHERE
  CREDIT_CARD_USED = 'X'
```

This returns:

```
Bill
Robert
Thomas
```

If we combine these 2 queries (where the customer is IN the first result, and NOT in the second result), we essentially exclude Robert and Thomas from the first result, and leaves us with Leroy and Sam from the final query:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM
  payments p
  JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      NAME
    FROM
      customers
    WHERE
      CREDIT_CARD_REGISTERED = 'X'
  ) x_registered ON x_registered.NAME = p.NAME
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      NAME
    FROM
      payments
    WHERE
      CREDIT_CARD_USED = 'X'
  ) x_used ON x_used.NAME = p.NAME
WHERE
  x_used.NAME IS NULL;
```

Which returns payment rows for Leroy and Sam:

```
|  NAME | AMOUNT | CREDIT_CARD_USED |
|-------|--------|------------------|
| Leroy |     45 |                Y |
| Leroy |     50 |                Y |
| Leroy |     75 |                Z |
| Leroy |     20 |                Y |
| Leroy |     50 |                Z |
|   Sam |     50 |                Y |
|   Sam |     40 |                Z |
```